# How to formulate (linearize) a maximum function in a constraint?

Tags: constraint, linearization, nonlinear-programming

How to formulate (linearize) a maximum function in a constraint? Suppose $C = \max \{c_1, c_2\}$, where both $c_1$ and $c_2$ are variables. If the objective function is minimizing $C$, then it can be simply done by applying $C \geqslant c_1$, and $C \geqslant c_2$. But if the objective function is non-regular, e.g. earliness tardiness, the value of $C$ will be larger than the maximum of $c_1$ and $c_2$. So my question is how to formulate it correctly?

Comment: Do you know an upper bound on $c_1$ and $c_2$?

Comment: Actually $c_1$ and $c_2$ are both variables and we have no tight bound on them.

Comment: Related post (not a dupe): [Single reference for Mixed Integer Programming formulations to linearize, handle logical constraints and disjunctive constraints, do Big M, etc?](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/57/491).  Specifically see [this useful reference](https://www.fico.com/en/resource-download-file/3217) from [this answer](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/58/491).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

(*I'm going to change $c$ to $x$ in my answer, since $c$ is usually used for cost coefficients, not decision variables.*)

We want a set of constraints that enforces $X = \max\{x_1,x_2\}$. Define a new binary decision variable $y$, which will equal 1 if $x_1 > x_2$, will equal 0 if $x_1 < x_2$, and could equal either if $x_1 = x_2$. Let $M$ be a constant such that $x_1,x_2 \le M$ in any "reasonable" solution to the problem.

The following constraints enforce the definition of $y$:
$$\begin{align}
x_1 - x_2 & \le My \\
x_2 - x_1 & \le M(1-y)
\end{align}$$
Then, the following constraints enforce $X = \max\{x_1,x_2\}$:
$$\begin{align}
X & \ge x_1 \\
X & \ge x_2 \\
X & \le x_1 + M(1-y) \\
X & \le x_2 + My.
\end{align}$$
The first two constraints say $X \ge \max\{x_1,x_2\}$, as you suggested in the question. Combined with these constraints, the last two constraints say that $X = x_1$ if $x_1 > x_2$ (so $y=1$) and $X = x_2$ if $x_2 > x_1$ (so $y=0$).

---

**UPDATE:** @EhsanK correctly pointed out to me that the first 2 constraints are not necessary. The 4 remaining constraints are sufficient to enforce the definition of $y$, and therefore of $X$.

---

Related:

- For more on logical constraints, see [In an integer program, how I can force a binary variable to equal 1 if some condition holds?](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/33/38).
- For more on big-M, see [Why is it important to choose big-M carefully and what are the consequences of doing it badly?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/236/why-is-it-important-to-choose-big-m-carefully-and-what-are-the-consequences-of-d).
- For a similar constraint, see [How to linearize a constraint with a maximum of binary variables times some coefficient in the right-hand-side](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/612/38). But note that in that question, only an inequality constraint is required for $X$, not an equality constraint.

Comment: Is there a particular name for this transformation? I am trying to find some type of academic source that I can reference this from for a paper I am working on.

Comment: @D.Gray Maybe, but I don't know of one. It's just a standard(ish) trick. If you really want to find a standard name, you could post that as a new question.