# How to linearize min function as a constraint?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, optimization, linearization, logical-constraints

I'm trying to solve an optimization problem including following constraint, and I need to linearize it in a maximization nonlinear programming model. Please help me to reformulate it with mixed integer programming. A part of my model is here:
   $$\min\ Z=-q_1p_1 \\
   q_1=\min\{b,ap_1\}$$
Note that $q_1$ and $p_1$ are non-negative variables and the others are parameters. 
I know that $$q_1\le b,\, q_1\le ap_1 $$ are helpful. But I'm trying to find another way to linearize it.

Comment: First of all, welcome to OR.SE. Can you provide more info on what you mean by "maximization nonlinear programming model"? And about the constraint: do you mean you have a constraint in a form of $x = min(b - q_1 - q_2, a)$? If so, then $x\le b - q_1 - q_2$ and $x \le a$ are your constraints.

Comment: @Vida, welcome to OR.SE. as Ehsan said it is simple to convert your min constraint into two inequalities. If you provide more details, I believe you will get a correct answer ( or maybe more than one) to your question.

Comment: I agree that we need more information. The suggestion of EhsanK is a good one, but may not always work. For example, if it is beneficial to choose $x$ small, then $x$ may end up to be less than the minimum, instead of equal.

Comment: if your constraint is of the form $min \ge$  RHS where RHS is either a constant or linear (affine) function of the optimization variables, then it is a convex constraint (min appears convexly) not requiring linearization, and can be handled as per @EhsanK 's comment.  If the constraint is of any other form  , then it is a non-convex constraint (min appears non-convexly), in which case it can be linearized per section 2,2 "Minimum values" in FICO MIP formulations andlinearizationsQuick reference https://www.fico.com/en/resource-download-file/3217

Comment: [This question](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/711/38) considers a **max** in a constraint, but the same approach might be able to be used here, using the fact that $\min\{x,y\} = x + y - \max\{x,y\}$ for all $x,y$.

Comment: @EhsanK thank you. I know that the constraints you've mentioned are helpful in case of maximization, but I'm looking for a linear constraint formed by binary variables.

Comment: @OguzToragay thank you. I mean by "maximization nonlinear programming model that the variables has negative coefficient in minimization objective function then, they multiply to another nonnegative variable.

Comment: @KevinDalmeijer You're right. I explain more about the problem in previous comments.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, although I linearized the case by "Minimum values" in FICO MIP formulations  you've mentioned, it didn't workout. Actually it made infeasibility state in my GAMS code and, binary variables doesn't take value.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 I'll check it. thank you

Comment: After all this, you still haven't told us what your constraint is. min(0 by itself doesn't constitute a c constraint.  Presumably, the constraint is one of, min $\ge$ something, min $\le$ something, or min = something.

Comment: @Vida As Mark said none of your explanations was really revealing the nature of your model. If possible, please edit your question and explicitly write down 1) Your objective function, 2) your constraints(at least their general forms).

Answer (score 14):

Here is an answer that uses the same approach as in [this answer](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/712/38), but converted from $\max\{\cdot,\cdot\}$ to $\min\{\cdot,\cdot\}$. I'll write the constraint in a more general form:

$$X = \min\{x_1,x_2\}$$

This method works if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are constants or decision variables (or one of each). (In your question, $X = q_1$, $x_1 = b$ and $x_2 = ap_1$.)

We want a set of constraints that enforces $X = \min\{x_1,x_2\}$. Define a new binary decision variable $y$, which will equal 1 if $x_1 < x_2$, will equal 0 if $x_1 > x_2$, and could equal either if $x_1 = x_2$. Let $M$ be a constant such that $x_1,x_2 \le M$ in any "reasonable" solution to the problem.

The following constraints enforce the definition of $y$:
$$\begin{align}
x_2 - x_1 & \le My \\
x_1 - x_2 & \le M(1-y)
\end{align}$$
Then, the following constraints enforce $X = \min\{x_1,x_2\}$:
$$\begin{align}
X & \le x_1 \\
X & \le x_2 \\
X & \ge x_1 - M(1-y) \\
X & \ge x_2 - My.
\end{align}$$
The first two constraints say $X \le \min\{x_1,x_2\}$. Combined with these constraints, the last two constraints say that $X = x_1$ if $x_1 < x_2$ (so $y=1$) and $X = x_2$ if $x_2 < x_1$ (so $y=0$).

Comment: @LarrySynyder610 thanks for your reply.The way you suggested wasn't helpful. The binary variable doesn't take value and it cause infeasible state in my GAMS codes.

Comment: I'm sorry it wasn't helpful. I am pretty sure that the method I outlined is correct, at least in general. Maybe there's something else going on in your model that is interfering with the constraints on $y$ somehow and causing the infeasibility -- or even maybe just an implementation bug. It's also of course possible that my method is wrong, though I think it's correct -- so if you see an error or flaw in my reasoning, please let me know.

Comment: @larrySynyder610 I checked all terms in my code GAMS. I'm sure it's correct. let me to explain it more.First, I use the method you mentioned and the model was infeasible. then, I use the constraints that I mentioned in my question and it didn't cause any problem.It seems the method isn't helpful for the case, and I keep working with these $$q_1\le b,\, q_1\le ap_1 $$ .Anyway, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hmm, OK, well, I don't see where the logical error is. Maybe someone else can spot it. Sorry this didn't help.

Comment: I found a different linearization for $\min$ [here](https://www.fico.com/fico-xpress-optimization/docs/dms2019-04/mipform/dhtml/chap2s1_sec_ssecminval.html). Instead of your single variable $y$ they introduce two variables $d_1$ and $d_2$, with these constraints:
\begin{split}
L_1 &\leq x_1 \leq U_1 \\
L_2 &\leq x_2 \leq U_2 \\
\\
X &\leq x_1 \\
X &\leq x_2 \\
X & \geq x_1 - (U_1 - L_{min})(1 - d_1) \\
X & \geq x_2 - (U_2 - L_{min})(1 - d_2) \\
d_1 &+ d_2 = 1
\end{split}
@LarrySnyder610 Could there be an advantage to using this approach instead of yours, or the other way around?

Comment: Probably, but I don't know of any guidance that would help you know a priori which one is better