# How to linearize the Min function while letting the binary variable to be fixed for x1==x2 as well?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linearization, logical-constraints

As discussed [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/1160/how-to-linearize-min-function-as-a-constraint), the `min` function, *i.e* $X = \min\{x_1,x_2\}$, can be linearized as follows:

\begin{align}
X & \le x_1 \\
X & \le x_2 \\
X & \ge x_1 - M(1-y) \\
X & \ge x_2 - My.
\end{align}
In this way, when $x_1<x_2$ then the binary variable $y$ is equal to $1$. However, when $x_1>x_2$ then $y=0$. Nevertheless, for $x_1==x_2$, the binary variable y can either take $0$ or $1$ (free).
How can I force $y$ also to be equal to $1$ for $x_1==x_2$ in the above linearization?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the contrapositive $y=0 \implies x_1 \not= x_2$, equivalently, $y=0 \implies (x_1 < x_2 \lor x_1 > x_2)$.  Introduce a small constant tolerance $\epsilon>0$, two additional binary variables $z_1$ and $z_2$, and the following constraints:
\begin{align}
1 - y &\le z_1 + z_2 \tag1 \\
x_1 +\epsilon - x_2 &\le M(1-z_1) \tag2 \\
x_2 +\epsilon - x_1 &\le M(1-z_2) \tag3
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ enforces $\neg y \implies (z_1 \lor z_2)$. Constraint $(2)$ enforces $z_1 \implies x_1 + \epsilon \le x_2$.  Constraint $(3)$ enforces $z_2 \implies x_2 + \epsilon \le x_1$.

Comment: Thanks. Do the following set of constraints work as well? 
$X \leq x_1 \\
X \leq x_2 \\
X \geq x_1 -Mz \\
X \geq x_2 -M(1-z) \\
x_1 \leq x_2 +Mz $

In this way, the first 4 constraints entitle X to be the min(x1,x2). Also, for x1>x2, z =1 and for x1<x2, z=0. Moreover, the last constraint forces y to be zero for x1=x2 as well (Not free anymore). Indeed, z is one's complement of the `y` in the original question.
In my problem, x2 is constant and all variables X,x1, are non-negative. I am not sure if it does anything to do with it. @robpratt

Comment: No, $X=x_1=x_2$ is feasible for either value of $z$.

Answer (score 2):

side comment : in many tools you can use min directly and then you do not need to linearize.

In OPL CPLEX

```
dvar int x in 0..10;
dvar int y in 0..10;
dvar int z in 0..10;

maximize (x-y);
subject to
{
  z==minl(x,y);
}
```

works fine

And

```
dvar int x in 0..10;
dvar int y in 0..10;
dvar int z in 0..10;

dvar boolean xlessthany;


subject to
{
  x==y;
  z==minl(x,y);
  xlessthany==(x<=y);
}
```

if you want a boolean decision variable to know whether x is less than y

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I am interested in the general linearization of min operator while making sure that the auxiliary binary variable stays 1 for x1<=x2 @alex-fleischer

Answer (score 1):

Once we have remembered that $\min f(x)=-\max (-f(x))$, we wish Boolean variable $y$ is forced to $1$ whenever $y$ is free to be $1$ or $0$, so we can add $-y$ to the objective function $Z=-q_1p_1$, so that $Z’=-q_1p_1-y$.

In this way, $\min Z’$ forces $y$ to be equal to $1$ when $x_1=x_2$ because of $$\min Z’=\min(-q_1p_1) + \min(-y)= \min Z - \max y.$$

In fact, $\max(y) \implies y=1$ whenever $y$ is free to be $1$ or $0$.