# Strong relaxations for binary variables

Tags: binary-variable, relaxation, semidefinite-programming

Having the following optimization problem that models $\sum_i\min(c_i, C)$:
$$
\min_{\mathbf{Y},\,\,\{x_i\}_i} \sum_i^{n} c_ix_i + C(1-x_i)
$$
and where

- $C$ is a positive constant,
- each $x_i$ is a binary variable that can take values in $\{0, 1\}$,
- $c_i\in\mathbb{R}$ is variable whose square $c_i^2$ is constrained by the linear equality:
  $$c_i^2 = \text{trace}(\mathbf{A}_i\mathbf{Y}),$$
  with $\mathbf{Y}$ being a symmetric PSD matrix and $\mathbf{A}_i$ a symmetric real matrix.

Since the number of binary variables $x_i$ can be quite large (more than 100), I have experimented with a semidefinite (SDP) relaxation that drops the binary constraint of each $x_i$. Specifically, I am optimizing $n$ 3x3 PSD matrices $\mathbf{X}_i$ that have the following desired rank-1 global optimum (which I am not currently achieving):
$$
\mathbf{X}_i = \begin{bmatrix}
x_i^2 & x_ic_i & x_i \\
& c_i^2 & c_i \\
& & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Besides the equality constraints that fix the values of $c_i^2$ and $1$, I also impose the binary constraint $x_i^2 - x_i = 0$. However, these constraints are not enough since the trivial solution $c_ix_i=0$ and $x_i=x_i^2=1$ remains feasible regardless of the value of $c_i^2$.

Since my problem is bounded $c_i^2,C<M$, for any possible value of $c_i$ and $C$, a stronger relaxation can be achieved using the big-M method [as explained here for a LP problem](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/1174/10934). However, I am still unable to achieve the desired rank-1 matrix solution $\mathbf{X}_i$ of above.

The result from [Exact SDP Relaxations with Truncated Moment Matrix for Binary Polynomial Optimization Problems](https://optimization-online.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/5279.pdf) states:

> For binary polynomial optimization problems (POPs) of degree $d$ with $n$ variables, we
> prove that the $[(n + d − 1)/2]$th semidefinite (SDP) relaxation in Lasserre’s hierarchy
> of the SDP relaxations provides the exact optimal value.

seems relevant. However I think it is not applicable to my problem, since my problem also involves the continuous variable $c_i^2 = \text{trace}(\mathbf{A}_i\mathbf{Y})$.

Is it possible that achieving the desired rank-1 matrices is impossible due to the strong non-convexity induced by the binary variables?