# Linearizing objective function with absolute differences

Tags: linear-programming, linearization, absolute-value

I want to turn this objective function

$$\max \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^N |TX_i^T - TX_j^T|$$

where $T$ is just a vector with increasing integers (e.g $[1 \ 2]$) and $X_i$ is a vector with $n$ variables like $[x_{11} \ x_{12}]$.

Is there a way to turn this objective function into a linear form?
And how can I do that?
 My problem is that I don't quite fully understand it when I have to *maximize* the objective function.

Comment: X-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/q/350859/91764

Answer (score 4):

Introduce a new variable $z_{i,j}$ to represent the summand, and apply the linearization of $\max$ described [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/711/how-to-formulate-maximum-function-in-a-constraint/712#712).  Explicitly, the problem is to maximize $\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^N z_{i,j}$ subject to
\begin{align}
z_{i,j} &\ge T X_i^T-T X_j^T\\
z_{i,j} &\ge -T X_i^T+T X_j^T\\
z_{i,j} &\le T X_i^T-T X_j^T + M_{i,j}^1 (1-y_{i,j})\\
z_{i,j} &\le -T X_i^T+T X_j^T+ M_{i,j}^2 y_{i,j}\\
y_{i,j} &\in \{0,1\}
\end{align}
Here, $M_{i,j}^1$ is a small upper bound on $z_{i,j} - T X_i^T + T X_j^T$, and $M_{i,j}^2$ is a small upper bound on $z_{i,j} + T X_i^T - T X_j^T$.

The idea is that $y_{i,j}=1$ forces $z_{i,j} = T X_i^T-T X_j^T$, and $y_{i,j}=0$ forces $z_{i,j} = -T X_i^T+T X_j^T$.

Comment: thanks a lot, is there a way to decide how high i can set M^1 and M^2?

Comment: You should set those big-M values as small as possible, based on $T$ and bounds on $X$, without cutting off useful solutions.  Do you have bounds on $X$?